# How do you add together numbers in string?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def sum_digits(user_input):
    total = 0
    for c in user_input:
        if c.isdigit(): 
            total += int(c)
            print(total)
```

The problem I'm having is that when lets say the user enters car888 the program will output (8, 16 and 24)
But all I want it to output is the sum of the numbers so just 24.

Comment: Then move the print out of the block

Comment: Didn't understand what u meant by block at first haha. I see what u mean now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `print` is simply place in the wrong position. You currently have it nested under the if statement and so it will return each individual iteration.

Try this:

```
def sum_digits(user_input):
    total = 0
    for c in user_input:
        if c.isdigit(): 
            total += int(c)
    print(total)
```

Comment: You're a life saver.